# Cedar-like conifer near Kaladar, Ontario

Tags: species-identification, botany

What species of conifer is this?

- Cedar-like leaves
- Rocky terrain near Kaladar, Ontario
- Sept 29, 2022
- Approx 15 feet tall; approx 6 inches DBH

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly looks like the Eastern Red Cedar, *Juniperus virginiana*.  They are very fond of disturbed areas and can be any where from a scrubby bush to a decent tree.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniperus_virginiana) has more info.  Your location is a little north of the distribution maps, but not much, and it is warmer these days...